# Why foreach loop stopped execution on file_get_content error

Tags: php, file-get-contents

In my php code there is a foreach loop of urls as follow.

```
foreach ($url as $ur) { 
echo file_get_contents($ur);
}
```

But the problem is that is any of the url is unreachable or failed to open stream foreach stopped execution and produce no results.
Only i get this error as a result.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(www.example.com): failed to open stream: A 
connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond. in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\project\simple_html_dom.php on line 83
```

I using simple HTML DOM php for scraping urls. 
What i actually want to skip the url and continue execution.

Comment: Try to wrap the function in a try and catch but don't throw the exception in the catch block.

Comment: Should i wrap the whole foreach or only file_get_content ?

Comment: Nope. Only the part inside the loop `echo file_get_contents($ur);`.

Comment: @NMoeini try/catch is useless if your are not dealing with anything that actually throws exceptions. A Warning such as in this case here, is not an exception.

Comment: Such a warning by itself should not stop the rest of the loop from executing. That requests timing out add to your total script execution time and it therefor gets terminated eventually, is however possible.

Comment: You are right @misorude. You can't do much for timeouts because it does not throw throwable. However, this is a way to avoid breaking operation in a loop when it is desirable.